# dojo carousel header position

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

All I am using [dojox/mobile/Carousel](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/mobile/Carousel.html#id2).

I would like to display the `mblCarouselHeaderBar` at the bottom of the control instead of top. anyone knows how to do it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the carousel position through css by setting margin-top of carousel header bar and change position to absolute instead of relative of carousel pages.

Header of Carousel

```
.mblCarouselHeaderBar {
padding: 1px;
margin-top: 123px;
}
```

Pages or images of Carousel

```
.mblCarouselPages {
text-align: center;
margin-top: -153px;
position: absolute;
}
```